# redefine printf(), sprintf(), etc. arm-none-eabi toolchain

Tags: c++, c, arm, embedded, platformio

I'm setting up and environment with the gcc-arm-none-eabi toolchain (currently 7.2.1). This is for an ARM cortex M4 embedded device.

I'd like to redefine printf for the entire project, but I'm having trouble. I want to use [this](https://github.com/mpaland/printf) implementation. I've installed this into the project, and I can use it by calling, for example: `printf_("Test: %i",5);` and everything works as expected.

Now I want to set it as the default printf function. If I uncomment: `#define printf printf_`, I get the following error:

```
/home/timv/.platformio/packages/toolchain-gccarmnoneeabi@1.70201.0/arm-none-eabi/include/c++/7.2.1/cstdio:127:11: error: '::printf' has not been declared
   using ::printf;
```

later on:

```
src/LoggerTask.cpp:62:5: error: 'printf' was not declared in this scope
```

In that file I found this line:

```
#undef printf
```

When I comment that line out, the project builds, and printf works. This is good, but I would like to have my project function without patching the toolchain.

How should I go about doing this? What other information would be helpful?

Comment: Do you need a C solution or just a C++ one?

Comment: Why would you `#undef printf` in your `LoggerTask.cpp`? `f I uncomment: #define printf printf_` - in which file is that define located?

Comment: It is a bad idea to redefine standard C names (confusing, and could be undefined behavior). Can't you use `myprintf` instead in your source code?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pointer to `printf` using the next example. You need to create helper files (named "printf_helper.h" and "printf_helper.cpp" in this example). And include "printf_helper.h" (*better after all other included headers*) to a file where you want to use `printf`.

#### printf_helper.h:

```
#ifndef PRINTF_HELPER_H
#define PRINTF_HELPER_H

namespace helper {
  typedef int (*printf_t) (const char * format, ...);
  extern const printf_t printf_ptr;
}

#endif /* PRINTF_HELPER_H */
```

#### printf_helper.cpp:

```
#include "printf_helper.h"
#include <cstdio>

namespace helper {
  const printf_t printf_ptr = std::printf;
}
```

#### Example of usage in main.cpp:

```
// all other included headers
#include "printf_helper.h"

int main() {
  helper::printf_ptr("Hello, %s!\n", "World");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new file to your compilation:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
int vprintf_(const char* format, va_list va);
int printf(const char *str, ...) {
     va_list va;
     va_start(va, str);
     int ret = vprintf_(str, va);
     va_end(va);
     return ret;
}
```

Compile and link against the resulting  object while creating the compilation output. That's all. Because of how linker works, the linker should pick your symbol, instead of the one provided by newlib. Alternatively, you could use `--wrap=printf` linker option to simply wrap the symbol.